# How to get more results over 50 set by maxResults?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

This source code working well.
The maxResults cannot be set over the number 50.

*API call to youtube.search.list failed with error: Invalid value '150'. Values must be within the range: [0, 50] (line 32, file "Code")*

How to get more results?

```
function Search_YouTube_videos_ByChannel() {
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    channelId:'UCZFUrFoqvqlN8seaAeEwjlw',
    maxResults: 50
  });
    var title = "";
    var id = "";
    var last_row = 0;
    var spread_active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = spread_active.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
        var item = results.items[i];
        title = item.snippet.title;
        id = item.id.videoId;
        last_row = sheet1.getLastRow() + 1;
        sheet1.getRange(last_row, 1).setValue(title);
        sheet1.getRange(last_row, 2).setValue(id);
        last_row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#maxResults) for `maxResults`, the values have to be "Acceptable values are 0 to 50,". There is no way to going over this, as this is the way the API is intended to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve all items from `channelId`.
- You want to put `title` and `videoId` from the retrieved items to the column "A" and "B" of "Sheet1".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- When you want to retrieve the items more than 50, please use `nextPageToken`.
- In your script, `setValue()` is used in the for loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. So in your case, you can use `setValues()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

When you use this, please enable YouTube Data API at Advanced Google Services.

```
function Search_YouTube_videos_ByChannel() {
  var items = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var temp = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
      channelId:'UCZFUrFoqvqlN8seaAeEwjlw',
      maxResults: 50,
      pageToken: pageToken,
    });
    Array.prototype.push.apply(items, temp.items);
    pageToken = temp.nextPageToken || "";
  } while (pageToken);
  var spread_active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spread_active.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = items.map(function(e) {return [e.snippet.title, e.id.videoId]});
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- When this script is run, 410 items are retrieved.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, I got 410 items. I think this answer will solve all issues with requests has more than 50 items (maxResults: 50 with  pageToken: pageToken,)

Comment: @Cătălin George Feștilă Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Just note YouTube has a soft limit of 500 results from the search call.

Comment: @johnh10 Thank you for your additional information. I think that the information will be useful for users.